# c code compilation error on mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors, osx-yosemite

I am a trying to compile a simple c code on my macbook pro (yosmite 10.10.2, Xcode 6.2).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "htslib/sam.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    htsFile *fp_in = NULL;

    fp_in = hts_open(argv[1],"r");

    if(NULL == fp_in){
        printf("can't open file\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I have compilation error.

```
gcc -g -Wall -v test_bam.c -o test_bam

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_hts_open", referenced from:
      _main in test_bam-7d7369.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have all the necessary header files under /usr/local/include directory. I have googled a lot, and it seems a simple linking problem. I tried compiling with -L argument still I have the same problem. Then I tried with -arch i386 , but it does not work either. I have also tried clang as one of the similar post suggested, but same problem.

After struggling for six hours, I am posting here.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `-l` instead of `-L`.

Comment: Hi I have tried with `-l` too, but it says 'sam.h' not found!. 


`gcc -g -Wall -L /usr/local/include/htslib/ -lsam test_bam.c -o test_bam`


`test_bam.c:12:10: fatal error: 'sam.h' file not found
#include "sam.h"`

Comment: Use `-I` for include search path, `-L` for library search path and `-l` for linking a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include **htslib/sam.h** header you have to look in /usr/local/include folder, so add **-I/usr/local/include** to your compiler flags.

Also you will have to change line 2 of your c file to:

```
#include <htslib/sam.h>
```

Angular braces mean to search for the header file in system directories while your syntax, with quotation marks, means to search in local path.

Assuming your hts library is installed in /usr/local/lib/ you may add **-L/usr/local/lib** flag.

Finally add **-lhts** flag to link with libhts library.

```
gcc -g -Wall -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/lib -lhts test_bam.c -o test_bam
```